# Get multiple text elements from XML

Tags: xml, powershell

How can I get multiple text element from an XML document in PowerShell?

Here's an example:

```
<log>
  <logentry revision="152">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-03-28T14:54:27.443978Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 1

* Note 1
* Note 2</msg></logentry>
  <logentry revision="153">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-03-28T16:24:43.438847Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 2</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="154">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-03-31T16:00:01.590373Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 3</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="155">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-04-01T09:28:09.744015Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 4

* Note 3
* Note 4
    </msg>
  </logentry>
</log>
```

This is an output of `svn log` for specific revisions. I want to simplify log messages since the last script run for manual summarising into a text file. I can read the existing file, parse the last revision and call `svn log` for the new revisions. I'd like to get the following text output of the above XML document:

```
Summary 1
* Note 1
* Note 2
Summary 2
Summary 3
Summary 4
* Note 3
* Note 4
```

Also notice the inconsistent final newline in each "logentry/msg" element. All empty lines shall be removed, but all other line breaks must be kept. Also each "msg" element must be in a new line, not multiple messages glued together in one output line (which I now have, sort of).

Here's my current code:

```
$newMsgs = ($xml.log.logentry.msg).Replace("`n`n", "`n").Trim()
```

But it doesn't put each "msg" in a separate line. Also I don't understand what it does exactly and when it'll break. I am familiar with the BCL from C# but not so much PowerShell and its own way to solve things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily just split the messages on the new line character and then filter out lines which do not have any content. In case you want to remove lines which only consist of whitespace, you could trim them before filtering. Here's an example:

```
$xml.log.logentry.msg -split "`n" | Foreach { $_.Trim() } | Where { $_ }
```

As a side note, you have a minor error in your sample xml. The first `msg` element is never closed.

Here's a full sample using your sample xml and filtering using the script above:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<log>
  <logentry revision="152">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-03-28T14:54:27.443978Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 1

* Note 1
* Note 2</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="153">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-03-28T16:24:43.438847Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 2</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="154">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-03-31T16:00:01.590373Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 3</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="155">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2014-04-01T09:28:09.744015Z</date>
    <msg>Summary 4

* Note 3
* Note 4
    </msg>
  </logentry>
</log>
"@

$xml.log.logentry.msg -split "`n" | Foreach { $_.Trim() } | Where { $_ }
```

This yields the requested output:

```
Summary 1
* Note 1
* Note 2
Summary 2
Summary 3
Summary 4
* Note 3
* Note 4
```

Comment: The XML error must be a typo as I've copied it out of a console window. So your command gives me an array of strings, one per line, I guess. How can I convert it into a string with consistent newline characters to write it back to the file, together with the previous content?

Comment: You want it added back into the XML and then saved? When you say "consistent newline characters", do you expect both carriage return and line feed or just the line feed character or do your not care if it's either or a mix, as long as they are on the right places?

Comment: No, I just use XML as source, but write everything in a plain text file. SVN can also give me plain text, but XML should be safer to parse. I prefer CRLF as that's what Windows uses, and SVN seems to return LF only. Right now I have some ugly mix of both, and missing line breaks between "msg" items. But it should be easy to clean existing line breaks with some Replace() calls.

Comment: Just save the result of the previous filtering into a variable called `$logtext` and then do `[string]::join("``r``n", $logtext).Replace("``r``r", "``r") | Out-File c:\myoutput.txt -Encoding UTF8` (just make the double backticks in the code a single backtick, I'm just having issues with stackoverflows handling of control characters), given that you want to save it with UTF8 encoding. That should ensure that there is both carriage return and line feed characters between each line and if there are mixed line feeds in the input it should remove the extra carriage return characters.